# TFS Get latest Version from Specific Folder

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I want to create at button to get latest Version of my code from a specific folder without using Team Explorer -> Source Control tree every time.

So I am trying to make and external tools reference to run the tf.exe [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx) command.

This is what I have so far.

[image]

When I run this is gives me this error:

**Unrecognized command option 'workspace'**

I cant figure out how to provide the workspace name?

Comment: Why take all this pain? You can right click on any solution/project node and click `Get Latest`. Or you can customize any toolbar and add the command there for easy access.

Comment: Because we have resources and assemblies that exist higher than the solution folder, so that is not an option.

Comment: I don't see you specifying the workspace option, so I'm not sure why you're seeing this error.  Have you tried adding /workspace:WORKSPACENAME (replacing, obviously, WORKSPACENAME with whatever your TFS workspace name is...?)  You do need the colon between the /workspace and the workspace name (which might lead to this error.)

Comment: Yeah i tried variations of that, it didnt seem there is a `/workspace`  flag on `get`

Answer (score 15):

You can omit the workspace name.  `tf.exe` can resolve the server path and local path mappings because it stores workspace information locally.

The command you gave is correct (assuming you have `$/Dev` mapped):

```
tf.exe get /recursive $/Dev
```

However it's critical that you have `$/Dev` mapped directly (not just having children mapped) and unambiguously (you cannot have `$/Dev` mapped in two different workspaces) or else `tf.exe` will not be able to determine the correct local path.

Since a given local path can only be mapped to a single server path, the easiest way to do this is simply by specifying the local path you wish to get.  For example:

```
tf.exe get /recursive C:\Dev
```

Again, this assumes that you have `$/Dev` mapped to `C:\Dev`.

Answer (score 5):

Command to get latest is

```
tf get /force /recursive /version:W<workspacename>
```

1 thing to be noticed is the workspace which you have not provided in the Initial Directory text box. Provide some path where it will download local copy of files (i.e. nothing but called workflow). Provide some path like C:\TFS\Apps

Comment: So I tried this `get  $/Source/Dev /force /recursive  /version:W<WORKSPACENAME>` and its have be the message Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'

Comment: yes thats another solution, but taking your case i wrote above answer

Comment: This will not get the latest version, this will force a get of the WORKSPACE version.  If there's a newer version on the server, it will NOT be retrieved.  You want /version:T to get the latest version.

Comment: Yeah iv tried that it resorts in the same message as the above comment

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the answer that Mrchief gave: if you install the [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) you can use the contextmenü in windows-explorer to check-in/out, etc.

Comment: I want to do this so  I have a one click update - without needing to use any other tools or browse to anything.

Comment: you can set VS to get the latest files on an check-out. Maybe this would even be easier?

Comment: Yeah I have that set - this is for periodic points throughout the day.